Unknown signal when using URLDownloadToFile()
The code is set up as following:
if (S_OK == URLDownloadToFile(NULL, link, destination, 0, NULL)) {
    cout << "Successed in downloading file no. " << count << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "Failed in downloading file no. " << count << endl;
}

The URLs are accessed from a .txt file successfully.
However, an error code of the following appears:
Failed in downloading file no. 1
Failed in downloading file no. 2
Signal: ? (Unknown signal)

Process finished with exit code -1

I'm using MinGW gcc compiler and CLion also jumps me to the disassembly page highlighting the following lines:
ntdll!KiRaiseUserExceptionDispatcher:
    mov    0xc0(%rsp),%eax          
WahCloseSocketHandle:
    nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1) 
WSAConnectByNameW:
    test   %eax,%eax                
AuthenticateLicense+79157:
    mov    %rbx,%rcx                
AuthenticateLicense+100211:
    mov    0x5b226(%rip),%r11        # 0x18007fbf0
WSPStartup+6764:
    lea    0x533b5(%rip),%rcx
WSPStartup+120248: 
    mov    %eax,%edi                
ntdll!RtlActivateActivationContextUnsafeFast:
    mov    %al,0x30(%rsp)           
ntdll!LdrShutdownProcess:
    nop                  
ntdll!RtlExitUserProcess:
    mov    %ebx,%edx      
KERNEL32!ExitProcess:
    nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
msvcrt!_exit:
    int3
msvcrt!_initterm_e:
    nop
__tmainCRTStartup:
    mov    0x6cc1(%rip),%eax 
mainCRTStartup:
    mov    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)     
KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk:
    mov    %eax,%ecx   
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart:
    jmp    0x7ffb8a48aa69 <ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+73>

with an <unknown> 0x0000000000000000 which the notification of "debugger was unable to disassemble function containing address 0x0000000000000000: Cannot access memory at address 0x0"
What should I do to resolve this?
